# Which pattern to use reading from configuration and start different runners using Java

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns

I have simple problem and want advice how to improve the design I will try not to give details of my implementation but to be more abstract.

I have a configuration file with xml structure.(but can be changed)

```
<configurations>
   <conf>
     <path1></path1>
     <path2></path2>
   <conf>
   <conf>
     <path1></path1>
     <path2></path2>
   <conf>
</configurations>
```

where path1 and 2 are paths to some files which are needed in the business logic where I do repeatable actions with this paths many times(like banchmarks)
Then using this paths I need to do some operations but the content of every conf is separated from one another they can run in parallel without problems.

So first I read the configuration and store them in a List and then iterate over the list and execute consecutively the business logic.

I am wondering how can I improve the design of my  decision?

I think I can use **Iterator** patter to iterate over the structure and to accomplished the repeatable logic for every cong to use the **Strategy** pattern.

Am wondering how to separate logic to use different **runners** for operations in every conf tag?

Comment: The pattern Strategy is a good option. The operation is execute for all the path of one conf or is execute only for one path of one conf?

Comment: The configuration is used for all the paths in one conf. To execute the business logic you have to use two paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in many things that could be change for your implementation.

It's important to take the parts that vary and encapsulate them, by this way, later,  you can alter or extend the parts that vary without affecting
those that don’t.

The parts that I suppose that could change are :

- The source of your conf, it could come from a file (XML, CSV, XLSX, Properties File ...),   your data base, etc.
- The configuration. New attributes could be added to one conf.

Maybe you don't go to use all the configurations, so I vote for load some configuration when you need this one.

If one business logic needs one conf from your xml file and another business logic needs one conf from your csv file,  your flexibility is not the best.

I propose the use of an utility class with the methods that you need to create/load your configuration from different sources.

I suppose that each conf has a name or an id. You could also add more properties as the list of path, the source type, etc.

A map is a better option to store your configurations. You could use a key as (confName, SourceType).

You could use MultiKey  from ([apache.commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/keyvalue/MultiKey.html)) to create the key of your map.

Ex:

```
Multikey key = new Multikey(confName, sourceType);
```

You could create an enum for the source types:

```
public enum SourceType {
    XML,
    HTML,
    CSV,
    ORACLE_DB,
    PROPERTIES;
}
```

Create one Singleton as utility class to create and load your configurations.(I recommend you to read the section of "Singleton" in the book [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html))

```
public enum ConfigurationLoader {
INSTANCE;

private Map<Multikey<String, SourceType>, Configuration> configurations = new HashMap<>();

public Configuration getConfiguration(String confName, SourceType sourceType) {
    Multikey<String, SourceType> key = new Multikey<>(confName, sourceType);

    if (!isConfigurationLoaded(key)) {
        loadConfiguration(confName, sourceType);
    }
    return configurations.get(key);

}

//helper meethod to know if the configuration has been loaded
private boolean isConfigurationLoaded(Multikey<String, SourceType> key) {
    return configurations.get(key) != null;
}

private void loadConfiguration(String confName, SourceType sourceType) {
    if (SourceType.XML == sourceType) {
        loadConfigurationFromXml(confName);
        return;
    }
    if (SourceType.CSV == sourceType) {
        loadConfigurationFromCSV(confName);
        return;
    }
    if (SourceType.ORACLE_DB == sourceType) {
        loadConfigurationFromOracleDb(confName);
        return;
    }
}

private void loadConfigurationFromXml(String confName) {

    //your imlementation to create the configuration from XML file
    // at the end you put the conf in the map
    //.....
    //configurations.put(key, configuration);
}


//Equals for the others methods
//private Configuration loadConfigurationFromCsv(String confName) { ....}
//private Configuration loadConfFromDb(String confName){...}
}
```

The Configuration class (I think that you need only this class, you go to have only fields to add and not behaviors):

```
public class Configuration {
private String name;
private SourceType sourceType;
private List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();

public Configuration(String name, SourceType sourceType) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.sourceType = sourceType;
}

public void addPath(String path) {
    paths.add(path);
}

public List<String> getPaths() {
    return paths;
}
}
```

You need to know the configuration that you want,so in your business layer, you could call your configuration as:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationLoader.INSTANCE.getConfiguration(confName, SourceType.XML);
```

Next step, create your threads and iterate over you business logic with your configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Hm, sounds a bit like you are desparately trying to apply design patterns to everything :)

(Which is actually not a bad thing as long as your main goal is to learn about patterns.)

As for the Iterator pattern, ok, you store your data in a list and somehow iterate over it. I would not call this applying the Iterator pattern. Iterators are already defined for most containers of the standard library. In most cases you do not directly use these. It is much more convenient to use an enhanced for loop or Java 8 streams, which can also automatically parallelize the iteration.

As for the Strategy pattern, this would be useful if you need to implement the logic of the different configurations in different classes. But as long as you only want to use different paths, this is probably overkill.